# onkeydown works on some websites and on some it doesn't

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to set some keyboard shortcuts for gmail. I use tampermonkey and onkeydown function. I found out that gmail is a special website, because I found that on many websites this approach works, but not on gmail. I tried these 3 options, but none work. What do you suggest?

```
   // @match        https://mail.google.com // ALL HAVE THIS LINE
```

OPTION 1

```
    document.onkeydown = keydown;
    function keydown(evt){
              console.log("hhwhehehheeheh");
    }
```

OPTION 2

```
    document.documentElement.onkeydown = keydown;
    function keydown(evt){
              console.log("hhwhehehheeheh");
    }
```

OPTION 3

```
document.body.focus();
    document.documentElement.onkeydown = keydown;
    function keydown(evt){
              console.log("hhwhehehheeheh");
    }
```

Comment: Option 1 worked for me.

Comment: Did it work in gmail explicitly?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not seeing any console output and therefore I though it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 1 is correct, the problem is the pattern: `// @match      https://mail.google.com`

Use the follow pattern instead: `// @match        https://mail.google.com/*`

The problem with your pattern is that only fits for `https://mail.google.com` without path, however from gmail the content is not served from `https://mail.google.com` it's always use a location with path like `https://mail.google.com/mail/...` so you have to add `*` to the pattern in order to load your script.

Using the second one `@match` with your script work well for me:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://mail.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

document.onkeydown = keydown;
function keydown(evt){
    console.log("hhwhehehheeheh");
}
```

See the [`@match`](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_match) for more details

Hope it helps,